# Show Action Bar icons using FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to show the action bar icons using FragmentActivity (with implements ActionBar.TabListener). I'm following this example : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs (EffectiveNavigation.zip) but i can't figure out how can i show the "search icon" (in my case) on the action bar, because for the moment i can only see the search option when tap the menu button.

**jpg**

[image]

I've tried to switch from FragmentActivity to ActionBarActivity but seems it does not support the ActionBar.TabListener.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
 * three primary sections of the app. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will display the three primary sections of the app, one at a
 * time.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
            // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
            // Tab.
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
 * sections of the app.
 */

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if(id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
                return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

            default:
                // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Section " + (position + 1);
    }
}

/**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_launchpad, container, false);

        // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_collection_button)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CollectionDemoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // Demonstration of navigating to external activities.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_external_activity)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Create an intent that asks the user to pick a photo, but using
                        // FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET, ensures that relaunching
                        // the application from the device home screen does not return
                        // to the external activity.
                        Intent externalActivityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        externalActivityIntent.setType("image/*");
                        externalActivityIntent.addFlags(
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                        startActivity(externalActivityIntent);
                    }
                });

        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.effectivenavigation" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CollectionDemoActivity"
        android:label="CollectionDemo"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @ColinGillespie yes, the app crash when i try to start

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `android:showAsAction="always"` for the search icon. The custom namespace only needs to be used if you are using the v7 support library, which does not seem to be the case. With that in mind, you should also change the namespace for your other menu item.

Comment: I offered a potential solution to their problem. I am neither critiquing nor requesting clarification from them.

Comment: @NasaGeek just saw your edited post, what do you mean exactly for custom namespace? Sorry but i'm new in Android development.

Comment: I'm honestly not terribly familiar with it myself. It essentially comes down to where certain xml attributes are implemented, though. You use the `android` namespace for system attributes, and a different namespace for custom attributes provided by a library (like the official support library). Here, you are using the `app` namespace, though you could have given it a different name. You should remove `xmlns:app` from your menu xml and change any `app:` to `android:`.

Comment: If you end up using support-v7 to handle your ActionBar, though, then you'll need to change the namespace back from `android` to the custom one for the `showAsAction` attributes.

Comment: @NasaGeek i'm using support library in order to use FragmentActivity, so if i change the "app" to "android" i got an error. If you check the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs) (EffectiveNavigation.zip) you can better understand how is made this example app. 

In addition, in the styles.xml the base application theme is android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar